# How are uid's assigned and generated in ios and android

Tags: android, ios

How is an UUID assigned and generated in android and Ios. I know that UUID and sell id are used together to track tapi ie events of the user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UUID is a randomly generated value with 128 bits. Typically you use its 32 characters String representation. It is most likely to don't get double values but you cannot be absolutely sure so if you heavily rely on its uniqueness, implement a check to see if that UUID is already in use.

https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsuuid

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/UUID.html

Comment: it's 128 **bits** / 16 **bytes**